# Querying Link Over REST API

Tags: here-api

I'm running a few car simulations using the HERE Routing REST API, and I'd like to be able to get the accurate speed limit for where the car is so that it doesn't go too quickly or slowly for the simulation.

I can see that the speed limit is included within a link.

However, I can't seem to find how to get a link given its Link ID, or if that's even possible with the current API.

In the old API it seems like there was a **getlinkinfo.json** endpoint which ought to do what I need, but using it on my current freemium account says that I'm unauthorized.

Is this a feature tied only to pro accounts, is it deprecated, or is there just some other way I have to go about this?

Comment: getlinkinfo.json from Routing API has been depricated for sometime now and the alternative is to use Platform Data Extension API . There is an example here (https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_get_any_link_info) which illustrates this apprach

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above getlinkinfo.json from Routing API has been depricated for sometime now and the alternative is to use HERE Telematics Advanced Data Sets API (https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html) The data is split into different layers and tiles which could be queried for link attribute information.